Extracting Song Titles
I have a songbook and want to be able to make up set lists from the book.  Typically extracting 18-20 songs from a total of 200, and putting them into a new document, for a specific gig.
I've worked out how to extract the songs in order and put them in new document by listing the page numbers in a word table.  I find the beginning of the song (always the title) and then expand the Selection range to the Page Break (always at the end of each song. It's then straightforward to copy that song into a new document and loop round to do the other songs. That bit works ok, but I also want a summary list of all the song titles alongside the page numbers in the table I provided.
I can find the start of each song title as it's always at the top of the selected song.  What I need to do is select from the beginning to the start of an embedded field code.
For example, if I turn on 'Show paragraph marks' on this song I see the text "Green, Green Grass{ TC "Green, Greed Grass" \f C \l "1" }".  I want to select the text from the start up to, but not including the "{" character. Then want to copy this song title and put it into the table where I got the set list page numbers from.
I'm aware also that this is not a standard curly bracket but Word's way of showing the start of a field code for the ToC (where the title can sometimes be shorter, to fit into the ToC).
If for the first part (extracting the whole song I can expand the Selection range to the Page Break, is there an equivalent wat to expand the selection from the start to the field code?
I tried varying the syntax of the bit that selects the whole song, which is:
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=NextPage) ' NextPage contains the page number of the song
Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
Selection.Copy

For the song title I substituted the third line with:
`Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToField, Name:="TC")

When I do that, the Selection.Copy command fails because nothing has been selected.

Have you tried rng.Copy instead of relying on a selection?

The Selection.Copy works for the main song page but not for the title.  I'm assuming the problem is with the Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToField, Name:="TC") statement.

Tried rng.Copy and got rte 4605 "... no text is selected"

I think that's because in that case, Word makes a "point" range immediately before the opening field code brace. So both Selection.Copy or Range.Copy will fail.
Starting from where you are, try this:
Dim srange As Long
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=NextPage) ' NextPage contains the page number of the song
srange = rng.Start
Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToField, Name:="TC")
rng.Start = srange
rng.Copy

You probably need to test that that second Goto actually finds the first TC field after srange but AFAICS it does.
[The documentation for the Range.GoTo isn't really up to scratch, because for example it is described as a Method when in fact it is a Function, so
rng.Goto What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=NextPage

doesn't actually modify rng
the parameters you need for some types of Goto are not described properly. I always suspected that someone just copied the documentation for Selection.Goto (which is a Method) and didn't fix it up properly. Also, historically, one or two of these constants had different values on Windows and Mac versions, which wasn't very helpful! I think that last problem was removed when Word 2016 came along, but I've never checked]

Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm afraid this didn't work on my PC.  I still got RTE 4605 '...no text selected'. I suspect the problem lies with the syntax of the line: Set rng = rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToField, Name:="TC") as this is not correctly finding the relevant field code.

@JeremyHalliwell I don't think there is anything wrong with the syntax of the line. It works here. However, when I first went back to check, it didn't, and I had to restart Word to fix that. Perhaps a corrupt doc., or perhaps a memory problem related to not setting rng to Nothing in my latest code. Perhaps worth checking you do that in your code. Is your rng "going" anywhere. Is the TC field definitely a TC field? You can select it and inspect the value of selection.fields(1).Type, should be 9. The TC isn't in a Text box or some such?

@JeremyHalliwell Setting the range's textretrievalmode properties doesn't seem to make any difference. That's all I've got for now.
